Why is MD RAID1 so much slower than the raw network disk?
I'm trying to configure MD RAID1 (using mdadm) with the --write-mostly option so that a network (EBS) volume and a local drive are mirrors of one another (the idea being that the local drive is ephemeral to my instance, but has better performance).
To vet this idea, I get a baseline performance estimate of my drive using the following two scripts.
fio -name=RandWrite -group_reporting -allow_file_create=0 \
  -direct=1 -iodepth=128 -rw=randwrite -ioengine=io_uring -bs=32k \
  -time_based=1 -ramp_time=10 -runtime 10 -numjobs=8 \
  -randrepeat=0 -norandommap=1 -filename=$BENCHMARK_TARGET

# Read performance
fio -name=RandRead -group_reporting -allow_file_create=0 \
  -direct=1 -iodepth=128 -rw=randread -ioengine=io_uring -bs=32k \
  -time_based=1 -ramp_time=10 -runtime 10 -numjobs=8 \
  -randrepeat=0 -norandommap=1 -filename=$BENCHMARK_TARGET

Results:

Network drive: 117 MiB/s write, 117 MiB/s read
Local drive: 862 MiB/s write, 665 MiB/s read

The problem comes when I introduce mdadm. Even when using a trivial no-mirror "RAID1", the write performance is severely worse when using the network drive.
mdadm --build /dev/md0 --verbose --level=1 --force --raid-devices=1 "$TARGET"
# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version :
     Creation Time : Mon Sep 30 14:22:41 2024
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 10485760 (10.00 GiB 10.74 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 10485760 (10.00 GiB 10.74 GB)
      Raid Devices : 1
     Total Devices : 1

             State : clean
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb


0-mirror RAID1 array backed by network drive: 69.9 MiB/s write, 118 MiB/s read
0-mirror RAID1 array backed by local drive: 868 MiB/s write, 665 MiB/s read

As we can see here, the write performance didn't change much for local drive (MD-raid vs. raw access), but it's severely impaired when using the network drive via MD-raid. Why does this happen?

Did you try to repeat the measurement in both cases? These measurements are affected by the state of the computer, which is usually not well controlled, and different measurements of the same setup can result in different numbers. E.g. do 5 measurements and calculate average and standard deviation.

I have run this experiment dozens of times and recreated the server/volume from scratch multiple times over the course. So it isn't a one-off issue, I can reproduce it reliably. I believe I found the cause, eventually, after running a matrix-style benchmark.
I haven't tried ZFS, Btrfs, or Bcachefs. These may be useful, but I wanted the simplicity of the RAID1 setup (where the drives are usable individually as normal drives without any special configuration).

While you're at it, can you please re-run fio with different bs, say, 64k this time?

Throughput on the raw drives increased up to 32k and then flattened, while IOPS went down (obviously).

Bcache was pretty much designed for the exact use case of fast cache to slow storage, you should try bcache :)

@RyanPatterson sorry, didn't get notification, I mean can you check how different the results would be when bs is 64k in both cases — for raw network and MD-network?

As near as I can tell, this is a failure mode caused by overloading the MD kernel module with IOPS.
When I modify my scripts to use iodepth=64 numjobs=1, I see no loss in performance on the raw drives, and my RAID1 write performance impact disappears.
Here are the final scripts:
fio -name=RandWrite -group_reporting -allow_file_create=0 \
    -iodepth=$IODEPTH -numjobs=$NUMJOBS \
    -direct=1 -rw=randwrite -ioengine=io_uring -bs=16k \
    -time_based=1 -ramp_time=10 -runtime 10 \
    -randrepeat=0 -norandommap=1 -filename=$DEVICE
fio -name=RandRead -group_reporting -allow_file_create=0 \
    -iodepth=$IODEPTH -numjobs=$NUMJOBS \
    -direct=1 -rw=randread -ioengine=io_uring -bs=16k \
    -time_based=1 -ramp_time=10 -runtime 10 -randrepeat=0 \
    -norandommap=1 -filename=$DEVICE

And here are the net results:



Metric
iodepth=128numjobs=8
iodepth=64numjobs=1




Local disk, write
629
766


Local disk, read
754
877


Cloud disk, write
117
117


Cloud disk, read
118
117


RAID1, local, write
526
775


RAID1, local, read
751
853


RAID1, cloud, write
59
117


RAID1, cloud, read
115
117


RAID1, both, write
61
117


RAID1, both, read
755
879



I am guessing that too many IOPS combined with the slower drive leads to excessive queue length, which then leads to some sort of lock contention in the kernel module. But I don't know enough of the details to be sure. What I have learned, is that I'll need a more accurate benchmark to properly decide if this approach is viable for my use case.

please remember to accept an answer.

Without knowing exact mdadm implementation, I'll write my educated guess on this.
I think that in RAID 1 setup, the RAID subsystem waits for both drives to acknowledge write operations before processing next file events. And then there might be additional delays introduced by the mismatch of performance between the drives, which would then contribute to the 69.9 MiB/s vs 117 MiB/s write speed.
I don't think it is feasible to create RAID arrays with devices where access speed is vastly different. RAID wasn't designed for this use case.
You might want to look at a cluster filesystem such as GFS2 or OCFS2, those might be better suited for your use case.

I was thinking the same; there's probably orders of magnitude difference in latency, which leads to a lot of blocking.

I tried to be explicit, but to repeat: these numbers are from unmirrored "fake" RAID1. As shown from the output of "mdadm --detail", there is only 1 drive at play when I ran these tests.

There are no two drives in the MD device, so the system always waits just for one drive.

RAID wasn't designed for this use case. - but Bcache is designed for this use case. Recommend OP look up Bcache

I didn't see OP asked for any recommendations.

You are probably bound by MD write bitmap. You can try disabling it (via --bitmap=none during creation or later with --grow), but be sure to understand that an unclean shutdown on a bitmap-less array means a full resync after restart.

Good guess! I can confirm that there is no bitmap in use, however. A bitmap would use the "bitmap" consistency policy, but you can see that the one I have is "resync". The docs say that by default mdadm only adds one by default for drives over 100G.
